# Dog not eating unless accompanied

Tags: dogs, behavior, eating

My 4 years old male Welsh Corgi has had this problem where he very often does not eat unless accompanied. We keep him in the backyard, and as soon as I leave him and close the glass door, he ceases eating. When I or someone he recognizes comes through the door and stays with him, he immediately starts eating.

There have been times when we placed food in his bowl and he doesn't eat until the next morning, when I come through the door to play with him.

Any thoughts or help would be great.

Comment: Is he fed as much as he wants?

Comment: If he's hungry, I'm sure that he's gonna eat. I don't think you need to worry. Maybe he just likes company. By the way...did someone in the past train him not to eat from strangers or not to eat until you say 'eat'?

Comment: @papakias We did train him to do a trick where we trained him not to eat the treat in front of him until said 'ok'...

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to dogs who are stubborn for food a good way to get them eating is to place the dish down with their meal, give them a good 15-30mins. If they don't touch it remove the dish and try again at supper time, dogs who see their dish always available tend to have an easier time snuffing than if it's only there for a limited time.

Don't panic he will eat :)

Answer (score 2):

Just leave food out for him and he will eventually eat when he gets hungry. Your dog may prefer eating with other people around, but he likely won't starve himself without them. Pets are pretty adaptable when it comes to eating. If you stay away from your dog's food bowl for long enough, he will learn to eat on his own.

Answer (score -1):

I had a lab that did the same thing.  I just sat down with him while he ate.  It seemed to be important to him.   I also had another dog in the house that would eat it.